# Installing and Configuring Shield for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have successfully installed both the license plugin and the shield plugin on my client nodes. The logs show it starting correctly, and i am able to authenticate using the credentials is supplied. However when i connect i am getting a 503 error. I went back through the docs to see if i missed something, but i don't see anything about configuring the data nodes after enabling shield. What am i missing?

```
{
  "status" : 503,
  "name" : "Vertigo",
  "cluster_name" : "cluster01",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.2",
    "build_hash" : "e43676b1385b8125d647f593f7202acbd816e8ec",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-09-14T09:49:53Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

From the client logs

```
2015-10-28 03:14:52,235][INFO ][io.fabric8.elasticsearch.discovery.k8s.K8sDiscovery] [Vertigo] failed to send join request to master [[Abominatrix][T6zFRQO7RG-thZmOWVk2Xw][es-master-e6mj9][inet[/10.244.85.2:9300]]{data=false, master=true}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[Abominatrix][inet[/10.244.85.2:9300]][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested: RemoteTransportException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: TransportSerializationException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: InvalidClassException[failed to read class descriptor]; nested: ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.AuthenticationException]; ]
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.shield.authc.AuthenticationException]` means you don't have Shield classes on the client, I believe. Check that you have the proper Shield jar on the client's classpath. Also, run `GET /_cat/plugins` on the cluster and provide the output.

Answer (score 1):

Andrei,

I figured it out. Since i am running containers that separate the master, data, and client nodes, i had only installed the plugin on the client nodes. Once installed the plugin on the master and data nodes, uploaded the image to docker hub and rebuilt the cluster, it all started working.

Thanks
-winn